# Column increment condition

Tags: awk

Check values in column 2, if the values are not increment of 50 then print row

```
Input file

1000 2450 1
1000 2500 1
1000 2501 1
1000 2550 1
1000 2601 1
1000 2650 1
```

**output desired**

```
error 1000 2501 1
error 1000 2601 1
```

**Using answer of Karakfa I tried**

```
awk '{$2%50 
{ err = FNR; exit } 
END { print "Invalid file on line", err; exit 1} 
print "Wrong File :", FILENAME }' file
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean "multiple of 50"? 2550 isn't an increment of 50 over 2501 either.

Comment: Or do you only take previous lines into account?

Comment: Benjamín, yes multiple of 50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '$2%50{print "error",$0}' file

error 1000 2501 1
error 1000 2601 1
```

if the value is not multiple of 50, the remainder mod 50 will be nonzero.

I guess this is what you're trying?

```
$ awk '$2%50 {err=FNR; exit} 
       END   {if(err) 
                {print "Invalid file on line:", err; 
                 print "Wrong File :", FILENAME; 
                 exit 1}}' file
```

note `END` cannot be in any statement, can appear only as a "condition", similar to `BEGIN`.

Comment: Hi karakfa, i try to adapt the solution like this but something is wrong..awk '{substr($0,5,4)%50
{ err = FNR; exit }
 END 
  {  print "Invalid file on line", err; exit 1} 
     print "Wrong File :", FILENAME
}' file   Please can u advise

Comment: Hi Karakfa, Tks but i will like to get the first line where the error is found .. Is this posible please

Comment: What is the error?  What is wrong?  Difficult to read from the comments.

Comment: Karakfa, that is exactly what I was looking for.. tks